# How can I prove that this equality is impossible?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to prove that:

> $$(6 + x^2) \mod 7 = 4$$

is not possible for $x\in \mathbb{N}$.

I know the proof would be by contradiction (i.e. assume we have a value of $x$ that solves this equation and reach a contradiction), but I'm not sure here to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not by contradiction, it is by computation.

Comment: You can simply plug in the $7$ values ($0$ through $6$) for $x$ and see that the equality does not hold.

Comment: @Govind Parmar : this doesn't look like a good problem for the contradiction technique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$(x^2+6) \pmod{7} = 4 \iff x^2 \pmod{7} \equiv 5 \pmod7$$
Now we have
$$
x^2 \equiv
\begin{cases}
0\pmod7 & \text{if } x \equiv 0 \pmod7\\
1\pmod7 & \text{if } x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod7\\
4\pmod7 & \text{if } x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod7\\
2\pmod7 & \text{if } x \equiv \pm 3 \pmod7\\
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, $x^2 \pmod{7} \equiv 5 \pmod7$ has no solution.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: If $6+x^2\bmod 7=4$, then $x^2\bmod 7=5$.